# is it possible making plural of 'conceit'?

Tags: nouns, parts-of-speech

i think, 'conceit' means pride or something like this.then it is an abstract form.but i find a sentence as_their conceits are sometimes not based on wit.

Answer (score 1):

*Conceit* can also mean an idea, particularly a fanciful, strained, or self-indulgent idea:

> The notion that good fortune always comes to those who work hard is a common conceit among the newly rich.

Your example sentence ("their conceits are sometimes not based on wit") probably uses this sense of *conceit*. It should be pretty easy to see how the word could be made plural in such a context.

Answer (score 0):

[Conceits](http://i.word.com/idictionary/conceit) is the plural of conceit. It is perfectly acceptable usage.